# web scraping with label with persian language

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to retrieve data from a persian website (url=https://bama.ir/car/detail-pqogkp5-peugeot-207-mt-1398)
I used bs4 but I couldn't find this label :
<span class="label>کارکرد 
Actually I need the value which equals to : 0 کیلومتر
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FYtQP.png)

Comment: There are many span tags with class label. Which one do u want? A screenshot would help.

Comment: I would like to help, but I don't know persian language (farsi?) Can you make a screenshot from the page and mark there information what do you want to get?

Comment: yes farsi , I added the screen shot to the question

Comment: @aref See my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = 'https://bama.ir/car/detail-pqogkp5-peugeot-207-mt-1398'
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, 'html.parser')

label = soup.find(text=lambda t: 'كاركرد' in t)
value = label.find_next('span').get_text(strip=True)

print(value)
```

Prints:

```
42,000 کیلومتر
```